# Can Anyone Review my Changes to Documentation?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, documentation

If I have a documentation edit up for review, and someone posts a comment on it, I assume that person had elected to review my changes.

Is my review now entirely dependent upon that person? Or can someone else review and approve/reject the changes?

Comment: I could approve it, so yes, someone else can review it ...

Comment: @rene Though we are speaking in veiled terms to avoid invoking the meta effect I think you have answered my question...

Comment: In all my evilness I considered to reject your edit ...

Comment: If you go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/76941?draftId=64113) do you see *STATUS:  
Awaiting approval*

Comment: @NathanOliver I do.

Comment: @rene Gah! Don't do it! Or at least suggest a better example first. I realized that the only thing I've used this for is tokenizing. So i was like, man I gotta add that in as an example. The elegance of this solution does not seem to have been conveyed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now<sup>1</sup> a comment does not mean your edit has been reviewed.  I can "review" a change, leave a comment and then close the window which leaves the review in the same state it was in but now it has a comment to you and future reviewers.

So no, just because someone leaves a comment does not mean your review can only be completed by that person.  Someone could come along and decide to approve the request even though the other user left comments.  Conversely that same someone could see the comments, agree with them and decide to reject the edit.

One thing you can do is go you your profile, click on the documentation tab and then go to proposed changes.  This will show you any changes that you have that are still pending.  You can then click on each one individually which will take you to the review and let you see the comments and pending status.

<sup>1. This is all subject to change when they release a actual review queue for Documentation changes.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

- You can vote on documentation if you have 15 rep
- You can comment in documentation if you have 50 rep
- **Anyone can review anything in documentation if you have 100 rep**

The comments on reviews are, for as far as I know, all related to the **review**.

Anyone can opt-in to that review, untill it is approved or rejected. Anyone can post a comment, without actually rejecting or approving that edit.

---

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though. If someone has commented they are obviously reviewing. If someone is reviewing is that still open to others to review? Or am I locked in with only that reviewer?